# Windows 10 Phone Build To Support Android APK

Tags: android, windows-phone, apk

I'm trying to run an `APK` to my `Windows Phone` which is running the latest version of `OS` - 10. I followed this [link](http://mspoweruser.com/how-to-install-android-apps-on-windows-10-mobile/) for installation. But I've failed, maybe due to `OS Build`.

From the list it inscribed there the models of windows phone, but not the `Build` no. 
Mine is

Model - `Lumia 535 Dual Sim`

**What is the `Windows Build` Minimum No. To run android APK?**

Comment: It seems that your question is not related to programming...

Comment: Hhmm.. I think I will just ask this in `SuperUser` .

Comment: The android subsystem was removed from windows phone 10 http://mspoweruser.com/microsoft-removes-android-subsystem-from-latest-build-of-windows-10-mobile/